# Ionic 2 Tabs-execute a method before switching to another tab

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I want to put some validation that should execute before the user changes the tab. From my understanding of IONIC life cycle events, `ionViewCanLeave` should fire up when the tab is about to leave. I found someone raised the same [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11845) but the solution [suggested](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11752) is not very clear to me.

If the validation fails I don't want the tab to be changed i.e somehow block the navigation to another tab

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `ionViewWillEnter()`?

Comment: I have 4 others tab so i don't think its a good idea moreover i want to put the validation on same page not on different page.As matter of fact ionicViewWillEnter() is working.Thanks for the comment.